# leaflet graphhopper and vuejs (nuxt) longs and lats inversing order

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, nuxt.js, graphhopper

Im trying to display a route with a leaflet polyline in vue js (nuxt), i receive all my points from the graphhopper api in an array where every point is an array like that [lgns-lat] the problem is that leaflet want the opposite [lat-lngs] for now i have this code and i wonder what is the best way to reorder my data from the api :

```
<template>
  <div class="search_wrapper">
    <div id="map-wrap">
      <client-only>
        <l-map class="map" :zoom="zoom" :center="center" @click="mapinfos" @zoomend="mapinfos">
        <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
         <l-polyline :lngs-lat="polyline.latlngs" :color="polyline.color"></l-polyline>
       </l-map>
     </client-only>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url: "http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      zoom: 8,
      center: [50.631942, 3.057497],
      markerLatLng: [47.31322, -1.319482],
      polyline: {
      latlngs: [ // datas from graphhopper api
        [11.58906, 49.932663],
        [11.589153, 49.932832],
        [11.589047, 49.932967],
        [11.588903, 49.933075],
        [11.589356, 49.93335],
        [11.589566, 49.933199],
        [11.589715, 49.933065],
        [11.589923, 49.932808],
        [11.590119, 49.932456],
        [11.590201, 49.932204],
        [11.590296, 49.931587],
        [11.590406, 49.930536],
        [11.590538, 49.929669],
        [11.590611, 49.929388],
        [11.59115, 49.927823]
      ],
      color: "#eb01a5"
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
  }
};
```

Comment: You don't show how you build the input data for `latlngs` - can you not simply reverse the `[lon,lat]` elements you get back from graphhopper?

Comment: i receive the data exactly like this from graphhopper api and i guess i need to treat the data before sending to leaflet, and i just put in the sample code here some points but in facts sometimes it's an array with  hundreds of elements.

Comment: OK. There's an option on the graphhopper api to receive simple `lon,lat` pairs rather than a GeoJSON polyline - that will probably help. See `points_encoded`

Comment: i see an points_encoded option but it doesnt give me an array, i don't really know how to treat that

Comment: You should use the official JS client: https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api-js-client that comes with a leaflet demo

Comment: i've added the api of graphhopper and the points are also in the other order.